# Embedding a GROUP BY subquery into a GROUP BY query

Tags: sql

My query requires ten columns, nine of which are aggregates (eight `COUNT`s & one `SUM`), `GROUP BY` the first column listed.  There are three tables.   My only issue is coming up with an accurate `SUM(J.Pieces)`.  `J.Pieces` represents the number of pieces within a delivery order, grouped by each route (first column).

I've tested this with the first two tables listed, and the `SUM(J.Pieces)` is accurate.  When I `JOIN` the third table (be it `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `INNER`), the numbers incorrectly skyrocket.  I'm guessing that it's looking at Pieces columns from other tables and adding accordingly.

Right now, I'm trying a subquery for the `SUM(J.Pieces)`, with the same `GROUP BY`, but I get the error, "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

I've also tried getting the number of pieces via `COUNT(JSP.PieceID)`, but that requires joining two more tables, and the subsequently throw off the numbers of the other counts.

```
SELECT    j.Routenumber (1000) , 
          Count(DISTINCT om.ordernumber) AS orders (1000) , 
          ( 
                   SELECT   sum(j.pieces) 
                   FROM     job       AS j 
                   JOIN     ordermain AS om 
                   ON       j.orderid = om.orderid 
                   WHERE    om.customerid = '5' 
                   AND      CONVERT(varchar,om.orderdate,101) = CONVERT(varchar,getdate(),101) 
                   AND      year(om.orderdate)='2019' 
                   GROUP BY j.routenumber) AS pieces (1000) , 
          count( 
          CASE 
                    WHEN oe.eventtype = 'ArriveHub' 
                    AND       oe.note LIKE '%ID#:%' THEN 1 
          END) AS received (1000) , 
          count ( 
          CASE 
                    WHEN oe.eventtype='PieceScan' 
                    AND       oe.note LIKE '%,P,%' THEN 1 
          END) AS pickedup (1000) , 
          count ( 
          CASE 
                    WHEN oe.eventtype='PieceScan' 
                    AND       oe.note LIKE '%,D,%' THEN 1 
          END) AS delivered (1000) , 
          count ( 
          CASE 
                    WHEN oe.eventtype IN ('3rdReturn', 
                                          'BadAddress', 
                                          'Closed', 
                                          'WrongTruck', 
                                          'HolidayCL', 
                                          'FutureReq', 
                                          'HolidayNA', 
                                          'LateTruck', 
                                          'LeftBehind', 
                                          'PaperPOD', 
                                          'TimesUp', 
                                          'Breakdown', 
                                          'Unsafe', 
                                          'Weather', 
                                          'Missort')THEN 1 
          END) AS redelivered (1000) , 
          count ( 
          CASE 
                    WHEN oe.eventtype IN ('Damaged', 
                                          'Refused', 
                                          'RefusedDam')THEN 1 
          END) AS sent_back (1000) , 
          count ( 
          CASE 
                    WHEN oe.eventtype = 'Delivered' 
                    AND       oe.userid > 0 THEN 1 
          END) AS backentered (1000) , 
          count ( 
          CASE 
                    WHEN oe.eventtype='Short' THEN 1 
          END)      AS short (1000) 
FROM      ordermain AS om (1000) 
JOIN      job       AS j 
ON        om.orderid = j.orderid (1000) 
LEFT JOIN orderevent AS oe 
ON        om.orderid = oe.orderid 
WHERE     om.customerid = '5' 
AND       CONVERT(varchar,om.orderdate,101) = CONVERT(varchar,getdate(),101) 
AND       year(om.orderdate)='2019' 
GROUP BY  j.routenumber
```

The goal is to come up with an accurate total of pieces (`J.Pieces`) for each Route Number (`J.RouteNumber`), and the number of times pieces were counted with the remaining columns.  I can get separate queries successfully, but it's problematic to get all of the desired info at once.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: If your only problem is "j pieces", then I think you could significantly simplify the question.

Comment: It's a proprietary cloud-based software with SQL capabilities.  Their tech staff is not sure what's wrong, so I'm trying other techniques.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to have the third column merely give the aggregate function SUM(J.Pieces), but when I JOIN the OrderEvent table, the results for that column go from 27, 61, 37 (which are correct) to 3776, 10645, 5525.

Answer (score 0):

if you have 1 order and that order have 3 events, doesnt matter how you join the third table now you have 3 rows instead of one.

Instead you use a correlated query:

```
  SELECT 
      ( SELECT COUNT( CASE WHEN oe.eventtype IN ('Damaged', 'Refused', 'RefusedDam')
                           THEN 1 
                      END ) 
        FROM orderevent AS oe 
        WHERE om.orderid = oe.orderid ) AS sent_back (1000), 

      ( SELECT COUNT( CASE WHEN oe.eventtype = 'Delivered' 
                            AND oe.userid > 0 
                           THEN 1 
                      END ) 
        FROM orderevent AS oe 
        WHERE om.orderid = oe.orderid ) AS backentered (1000)

JOIN      job       AS j 
ON        om.orderid = j.orderid (1000)
```